# After text fade cycle page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title is a bit vague, sorry about that.

I am wanting say three divs (just some text in them) to run through a cycle once.

This would be on page load. After this is played the site will finally be displayed.

I would like this to only happen once when you first come to the site as it would be annoying having to sit through it more than once. As the user will be constantly going back to the page this will be on.

Before I posted this I had one more look and found this Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/NMSpx/1/

Here is the JavaScript from the Jsfiddle

```
function tick() {
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");
    $obj.first().fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```

It is more and less what I want but for it to stop at the last div and it is only played once.

I feel that I might have to make a page with this separate and make the JavaScript load in a new page instead of the last div. This way I can just link the user back to this page without the animation?

Comment: Just remove the call to  tick(); from inside the tick function

Comment: I just tried that but it only cycles to the second text.. Preferably I would like three or four then for it to stop

Comment: Add a counter: http://jsfiddle.net/NMSpx/56/

Comment: Thanks for the help .. Could you make it an answer to the question so I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like this to only happen once when you first come to the site
>   as it would be annoying having to sit through it more than once. As
>   the user will be constantly going back to the page this will be on.

This part wasn't covered on the accepted answer. In order to do play the animation only once, even after the page is refreshed, simply [set a cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and read it before playing the animation:

```
var i = 0;
function tick() {
    if (i > 3) return;
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");

    $obj.first().fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        i++;
        tick();
    });
}

if (typeof Cookies.get('animation_played') == 'undefined') {
    tick();
    Cookies.set('animation_played', true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just tried to see your answer and it doesn't work. It could be as I have been on the page before though. Will it never play again if you have been to the page? heres a link to the page http://www.periodictablesearch.zackreid.com/

Comment: Its also showing two at a time. Which it shouldn't be, just incase you thought it was meant to

Comment: Check your JS error console. You need to import the Cookies plugin I linked there. https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Thanks thats it working now. Just need to figure out why two are being shown :) thanks again

Comment: Got it working now. Will it always remember that you have been on that page and not play the script?

Comment: I think that cookie will expire when you close the browser window. If you want it to last an eternity you can do something like:
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 999 }); which will last for about 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

To make it cycle a specific number of times, just add a counter to the tick() function:

```js
var i = 0;
function tick() {
    if (i > 3) return;
    var $obj = $(".major_data .commitment_box .commitment");

    $obj.first().fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function () {
        $obj.first().insertAfter($obj.last());
        i++;
        tick();
    });
}
tick();
```